# Can Smartface run Ipad Apps from the Apple Store

Tags: ipad, windows-10, smartface.io

I'd like to run an iPad App from the Apple Store on Windows 10, someone suggested that Smartface would do it, can anyone confirm?

I have already tried www.xpadian.com, but it doesn't appear to work, and a premium version that supposedly could, does not seem to be available.

Answer (score 0):

Smartface finally replied to me, and confirm:

> Unfortunately, it is not possible to run AppStore apps on Smartface
>   because Smartface App Studio is not a simulator. Smartface is a
>   cross-platform mobile application development software. But you can
>   make your application with Smartface and run them on our Emulator.